# TCP/IP handshake using Ada

Tags: ada, tcp

Is there any way to perform 3-way TCP/IP handshake in Ada without the use of c++ Pragma?

If so, does anybody have an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you’re using GNAT, the answer is to use `GNAT.Sockets`; from the spec of that package, there’s the server side (with `use GNAT.Sockets`):

```
Address.Addr := Addresses (Get_Host_By_Name (Host_Name), 1);
Address.Port := 5876;
Create_Socket (Server);
Set_Socket_Option
  (Server,
   Socket_Level,
   (Reuse_Address, True));
Bind_Socket (Server, Address);
Listen_Socket (Server);
Accept_Socket (Server, Socket, Address);
```

and the client side:

```
Address.Addr := Addresses (Get_Host_By_Name (Host_Name), 1);
Address.Port := 5876;
Create_Socket (Socket);
Set_Socket_Option
  (Socket,
   Socket_Level,
   (Reuse_Address, True));
Connect_Socket (Socket, Address);
```

If you’re not using GNAT, you may be lucky enough to find that your compiler provides an equivalent. If you’re using GNAT but want to see how they’ve done it, look at the body of `GNAT.Sockets`.

Comment: Many thanks @SimonWright. I can connect to the server now, however, I was hoping there would be some example of how to send and receive SYN,ACK packets over the connection, are there any examples of that?

Comment: `Connect_Socket()` calls the operating system service `connect(2)` which - way down in the OS - does the SYN/ACK dance and returns when the TCP/IP connection is complete (or has failed). I don’t see why you’d want to re-implement all that functionality.

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize that Connect_Socket() does the handshake. Thanks a lot for that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to control the sending of SYN, SYN-ACK and ACK packages youself, you have to circumvent the TCP stack, as that is what a TCP stack does for you, so you don't have to do it yourself.

How to circumvent the TCP stack depends on your operating system.

Comment: Actually, on most OSes I believe you can do this by opening a [raw mode socket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raw_socket). You still have IP then, but not TCP.